# Running customized PMD ruleset in Maven

Tags: maven, customization, rules, pmd

I would like to run my customized [pmd](/questions/tagged/pmd) rule set which is in my local disk D:\rulesets\java. I am using maven to build my application. I put the below entry in maven POM.xml

```xml
<reporting>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <rulesets>
                <ruleset>D:\rulesets\java\basic.xml</ruleset>
                <ruleset>D:\rulesets\java\braces.xml</ruleset>
                <ruleset>D:\rulesets\java\clone.xml</ruleset>
                <ruleset>D:\rulesets\java\codesize.xml</ruleset>
            </rulesets>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

When I run my PMD report (mvn pmd:pmd) it's not taking my customized pmd ruleset defined in pom file. How to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have the actual answer for you, but I will suggest not to have those rules stored outside control of Maven.  It is simply making your Maven project difficult to maintain in the future.  Anyway, I bet you can change the ruleset to `/java/FILENAME.xml`, and add `D:/rulesets` as a system-scope dependency for this plugin.  However, this is still not a good solution even it works

Comment: I checked [official plugin site](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html) and all is OK. Maybe problem is with content of your rules? Please add one by one and check again.